# show function's results at specific day

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I have this function

```
function show_contents(){
$post_id = 3135;
$post_content = get_post($post_id);
$content = $post_content->post_content;
$content_final =  '<p style="line-height:1; color:white; font-family:Georgia, serif;">';
apply_filters('the_content',$content);
$content_final .= '</p>';
return $content_final;
}
```

And i want to print the result at Monday.For print i have this code

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');
 $day = date("l");
 if( $day == "Monday"){
 show_contents();
}
```

But i see no contents at the post which i put the shortcode of XYZ Php Code plugin.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This was the solution finally 
$content_final .= $content .'</p>';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$day = date("l");

switch(date("N"))
{
 case 1: //Monday
 {
   show_contents(); break;
 }
 case 2: //Tuesday
 {
   // other function
   break;
 }

  // Add the other week days here if you nees (3,4,5 and 6)

 case 7: //Sunday
 {
   // other function
   break;
 }
  
}
```